# OMP in fortran: Parallel regions within subroutine ignored.

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, subroutine, openmp

I have the following problem with OMP in fortran:

While I have found a lot of literature on calling subroutines from within a parallel region, I struggle with the reverse process. That is, in a separate file I define a module which contains a couple of subroutines. These subroutines I would like to contain parallel regions. These regions should be executed in parallel every time I call said subroutines.

Now, the naive way of simply adding the OMP instructions inside the module's subroutines, as I would in the main program, does not seem to work. The program compiles and executes just fine, but all the while completely ignores the OMP statements (the -openmp-report=2 option doesn't identify these regions as parallel), thus running in serial. The main program in which I would like to use these subroutines also contains parallel regions which work without problem.

In the main program I include `USE OMP_LIB`, but including functions such as `OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()` in the subroutines gives me an error because `this name does not have a type`. Including `USE OMP_LIB` again, explicitly in the subroutines gets rid of this error, but still doesn't make the subroutines run any more parallel.

I am confused. Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

The module is (schematically) defined like so:

```
MODULE par_module
contains

SUBROUTINE sub1(var1,var2,var3...)
implicit none
    INTEGER ... !variable definitions

!$OMP PARALLEL &
!$OMP DEFAULT(NONE) &
!$OMP SHARED(v_shared1,v_shared2,...) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(v_priv1,v_priv2,...) 
      !content
!$OMP DO
    DO i=1,N
           !more conent
    ENDDO
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
END SUBROUTINE sub1

SUBROUTINE sub2...
!...
END SUBROUTINE sub2
END MODULE
```

Comment: Instead of the long description a fully compilable example would be better. How do you find out it doesn't run in parallel?

Comment: I assume you're compiling with the openmp flag?

Comment: You must have `use omp_lib` in or known to the subroutines if you use omp functions in the subroutines so that the interfaces will be known to the subroutines.   You say that the Intel compiler openmp-report doesn't report these subroutines.  When you run the program, what value do you get from `OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()`?

Comment: OMP in subroutines should work fine. I've done it many times. Could you show us how you're compiling the program? I suspect that you're only using the openmp flag when linking, not while compiling the individual files.

Comment: Yeah that was it, I was using the openmp flag in the makefile. Copying the subroutine into the same file did the trick.